# iText 2.1.5: How to change the size of a table column

Tags: java, pdf, itext

My code is working fine but I want to enlarge column "designation" - when I print to PDF, the text in column designation does not fit.

```
com.lowagie.text.Table tab = new Table(6, 6); // #rows, #columns
ResultSet res = state.executeQuery(…);
tab.addCell("Designation");
…
tab.addCell("PV-TVAC");

tab.setWidth(100);
tab.setTableFitsPage(true);
while(res.next()) {
    tab.addCell(res.getString("designation")); // doesn't always fit
    …
    tab.addCell(res.getString("PV_TVAC"));
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to *finally* posting on SO!) You may want to use a spelling checker. With no earthly way of knowing what `tab` can be used for (interface) or at least *is* (class), this question is hard to answer: please edit that into your question. [iText](https://itextpdf.com/legal) is *not* part of the Java RTE.

Comment: I use iText. I declare a table like this Table tab = new Table(6,6); in the priting in pdf

Comment: `I use iText. I declare…` Do not comment comments asking for clarification: update your question (That gets it on the (first) page of active questions again as a bonus…). Please decide on using [iText up to version 5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itext/info) or [iText from version 7.0 up](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itext7/info) and tag accordingly.

Comment: Beware API changes in the 7.0 range - in particular, ["Since 7.0.2 table layout algorithms were introduced"](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Table.html#Table-float:A-boolean-). Do you know [Lowagie's iText 7 Jump-Start Tutorial](https://leanpub.com/itext7jump-starttutorial)?

Comment: My code works well but the sentences do not fit the columns Designation I just want to increase the width.

Comment: What function do I want to use to increase the column

Comment: Neither in the 5.5.13 nor in the 7.1 docs I can find a constructor `Table(int, int)`.

Comment: `What function do I want to …` this is not chat: update your question. I still have no idea what API version you try to use or how `tab` really is declare.

Comment: this is all the code I'm using

Comment: //fct d'imprimer en pdf les donnees emanant de la base de donnees public static void VisualiserFacturePro(String strId) throws DocumentException { Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4) ; try { File applicationDir= new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"GeBujaPharmaSoft"); applicationDir.mkdirs(); File pdfFile=new File(applicationDir,"Facture.pdf"); PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile); document.open(); Table tab = new Table(6,6); Statement state = Connecter.ConnectDB().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("select designation,quantite_sortie,prix_unitaire ,prix_total,TVA,PV_TVAC from detail_cmd_cl,produit where num_cmd_cl = \'"+tmp+"\' and produit.idproduit = detail_cmd_cl.numproduit ");

Comment: tab.addCell("Designation"); tab.addCell("Quantité"); tab.addCell("Prix Unitaire"); tab.addCell("PV-HTVA"); tab.addCell("TVA"); tab.addCell("PV-TVAC"); tab.setWidth(100); tab.setTableFitsPage(true); while(res.next()){ tab.addCell(res.getString("designation")); tab.addCell(res.getString("quantite_sortie"));

Comment: tab.addCell(res.getString("prix_unitaire")); tab.addCell(res.getString("prix_total")); tab.addCell(res.getString("TVA")); tab.addCell(res.getString("PV_TVAC")); } //on ferme le tout res.close(); state.close();

Comment: }catch(SQLException e){} } }catch (DocumentException de) {de.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace(); } document.close(); }

Comment: API 7 and iText2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to wrap/reflow text in `com.lowagie.text.Cell`s.
`void com.lowagie.text.Table.setWidths(float[] widths)` (or its `int[]` twin) may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for those who try to answer my questions,I try to find the answer my self

tab.setWidth(110);
try {
                        Statement state = Connecter.ConnectDB().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                        ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("select designation,quantite_sortie,prix_unitaire,prix_total,TVA,PV_TVAC from detail_cmd_cl,produit where num_cmd_cl = \'"+tmp+"\' and produit.idproduit = detail_cmd_cl.numproduit ");

```
                    Cell cell = new Cell("Désignation");
                    cell.setWidth(58);
                    tab.addCell(cell);

                    Cell cell1 = new Cell("Quantité");
                    cell1.setWidth(10);
                    tab.addCell(cell1);

                    Cell cell2 = new Cell("Prix U");
                    cell2.setWidth(10);
                    tab.addCell(cell2);

                    Cell cell3 = new Cell("PV-HTVA");
                    cell3.setWidth(17);
                    tab.addCell(cell3);

                    Cell cell4 = new Cell("TVA");
                    cell4.setWidth(5);
                    tab.addCell(cell4);

                    Cell cell5 = new Cell("PV-TVAC");
                    cell5.setWidth(10);
                    tab.addCell(cell5);

                    float[] larg = {58f,10f,10f,17f,5f,10f};
                    tab.setWidths(larg);
```